# How to parse JSON using Node.js?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

How should I parse JSON using Node.js? Is there some module which will validate and parse JSON securely?

Answer (score 1145, accepted):

You can simply use [`JSON.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse).

The definition of the `JSON` object [is part of the ECMAScript 5 specification](http://es5.github.com/#x15.12). node.js is built on Google Chrome's [V8](https://developers.google.com/v8/) engine, which adheres to ECMA standard. Therefore, node.js also has a global object [**`JSON`**<sup>*[docs]*</sup>](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Using_JSON_in_Firefox).

Note - [`JSON.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) can tie up the current thread because it is a synchronous method. So if you are planning to parse big JSON objects use a streaming json parser.

Comment: Anyone know why that's not in the official documentation?  Or, if it is, where to find it?

Comment: @snapfractalpop: The documentation only describes functions, etc, which are part of node.js. Standard JavaScript features are part of [V8](http://code.google.com/p/v8/), node.js is built on. I updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: @FelixKling For what it's worth, there's a bunch of stuff here on node's github wiki: https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/ECMA-5-Mozilla-Features-Implemented-in-V8

Comment: here, i've published a demo where you can see and play with this answer online (the parsing example is in app.js file - then click on the run button and see the result in the terminal): [link](http://staging1.codefresh.io/labs/api/env/json-parse-example)

you can modify the code and see the impact...

Comment: Your answer requires prior knowledge of JavaScript syntax. How hard would it be to show a usage example?
JSON.parse(str); // is the noob-friendly and therefore better answer

Comment: if it's for app config data, you can use data = require('./file.json');  Despite what many people are claiming on this page; Node will *NOT* parse JavaScript if your file has .json at the end!  It will parse it as JSON.  This is by *design*

Comment: Is it also possible to guarantee at least some type safety? E.g. I have a class with certain fields. Is it possible to check that this is not just correct json, but json with exact fields, without explicit checks for `undefined` for exact fields? I know with typescript https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22875636/how-do-i-cast-a-json-object-to-a-typescript-class, but without it ???

Answer (score 680):

you can [require](http://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_module_require_id) .json files.

```
var parsedJSON = require('./file-name');
```

For example if you have a `config.json` file in the same directory as your source code file you would use:

```
var config = require('./config.json');
```

or (file extension can be omitted):

```
var config = require('./config');
```

*note that `require` is **synchronous** and only reads the file **once**, following calls return the result from cache*

*Also note You should only use this for local files under your absolute control, as it potentially executes any code within the file.*

Comment: If you are using this method to parse the file make sure to take the path into account for the require.  For example, you might need to do something like this: require './file-name-with-no-extension' (for example if the file is in the current directory)

Comment: @SnapShot true, added a concrete example.

Comment: Note that the response is cached. E.g. if you put above require call in a function, call the function, change the JSON file, and call the function again, you'll get the *old* version of the JSON file. Has caught me out a couple of times!

Comment: Note also that `require` is synchronous. If you want to async friendly use `fs.readFile` instead with `JSON.parse`

Comment: I ran into the gotcha where the required JSON was cached.  I created a module called [json-update](https://npmjs.org/package/json-update) (on npm) to solve that problem and simplify updating json files.

Comment: You can also run into problems if you use paths inside the JSON, so in my experience I wouldn't recommend this. I use relative paths inside a JSON and use the same JSON frontend and backend. After node.js convert the paths to absolute paths and caches the results, they don't work in frontend.

Comment: Will this approach just treat the file as JavaScript, thus potentially running arbitrary code in the .json file?

Comment: Be careful requiring JSON that will be modified during runtime. Require will cache the JSON whereas fs.readFile will not.

Comment: Remember that requiring a local file (not a dependency) requires an indication of it being a path. This is why this example starts with `'./'`. `require('config.json')` will not work.

Comment: ~~Does this solution work with absolute paths, or only relative ones?~~ It does work with absolute paths.

Comment: you can delete the data from cache like this `delete require.cache[require.resolve('./config')];`

Comment: here, i've published a demo where you can see and play with this solution online (the parsing example is in app.js file - then click on the run button and see the result in the terminal): [link](http://staging1.codefresh.io/labs/api/env/json-parse-example)

you can modify the code and see the impact...

Comment: Simple note: don't forget to use the `.json` extension! If your file does NOT have the `.json` extension, require will not treat it as a json file.

Comment: Ok, but this has nothing to do with "securtiy" and "JSON", this is just the way how to include the data fom a file into your program !?

Comment: @pkyeck: `delete require.cache[require.resolve('./config')];`? I think it's easier and more readable to use `fs.readFileSync` at this point.

Comment: @d11wtq: No. Despite what many people claim on this page, require('./file.json') is both faster than reading the file yourself and using JSON.parse and, it's easier to use for app configuration (or any data that will not change).  Node was **designed** to handle app configuration using this method; It's the whole reason it exists.

Answer (score 342):

**You can use [`JSON.parse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)**.

You should be able to use the `JSON` object on any [ECMAScript 5](http://es5.github.com/#x15.12) compatible JavaScript implementation. And [V8](https://developers.google.com/v8/), upon which Node.js is built is one of them.

> Note: If you're using a JSON file to store sensitive information (e.g. passwords), that's the wrong way to do it. See how Heroku does it: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars#setting-up-config-vars-for-a-deployed-application. Find out how your platform does it, and use `process.env` to retrieve the config vars from within the code.

---

## Parsing a string containing JSON data

```
var str = '{ "name": "John Doe", "age": 42 }';
var obj = JSON.parse(str);
```

---

## Parsing a file containing JSON data

You'll have to do some file operations with `fs` module.

#### Asynchronous version

```
var fs = require('fs');

fs.readFile('/path/to/file.json', 'utf8', function (err, data) {
    if (err) throw err; // we'll not consider error handling for now
    var obj = JSON.parse(data);
});
```

#### Synchronous version

```
var fs = require('fs');
var json = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('/path/to/file.json', 'utf8'));
```

---

## You wanna use `require`? Think again!

[You can sometimes use `require`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7165572/1461424):

```
var obj = require('path/to/file.json');
```

But, I do not recommend this for several reasons:

1. `require` is synchronous. If you have a very big JSON file, it will choke your event loop. You really need to use `JSON.parse` with `fs.readFile`.
2. `require` will read the file ***only once***. Subsequent calls to `require` for the same file will return a cached copy. Not a good idea if you want to read a `.json` file that is continuously updated. You could use [a hack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5726729/how-to-parse-json-using-node-js/25710749#comment43497504_9804910). But at this point, it's easier to simply use `fs`.
3. If your file does not have a `.json` extension, `require` will not treat the contents of the file as JSON.

**Seriously! Use `JSON.parse`**.

---

## `load-json-file` module

If you are reading large number of `.json` files, (and if you are extremely lazy), it becomes annoying to write boilerplate code every time. You can save some characters by using the [`load-json-file`](https://www.npmjs.org/package/load-json-file) module.

```
const loadJsonFile = require('load-json-file');
```

#### Asynchronous version

```
loadJsonFile('/path/to/file.json').then(json => {
    // `json` contains the parsed object
});
```

#### Synchronous version

```
let obj = loadJsonFile.sync('/path/to/file.json');
```

---

## Parsing JSON from streams

If the JSON content is streamed over the network, you need to use a streaming JSON parser. Otherwise it will tie up your processor and choke your event loop until JSON content is fully streamed.

There are [plenty of packages available in NPM](https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=json%20parse%20stream) for this. Choose what's best for you.

---

## Error Handling/Security

If you are unsure if whatever that is passed to `JSON.parse()` is [valid JSON](http://json.org/), make sure to enclose the call to `JSON.parse()` inside a `try/catch` block. A user provided JSON string could crash your application, and could even lead to security holes. Make sure error handling is done if you parse externally-provided JSON.

Comment: `and could even lead to security holes` out of curiosity, how?

Comment: @natario: We are talking about server-side JS here. Suppose someone is parsing user-supplied JSON. If the assumption is that the JSON is always well formed, an attacker can send some malformed JSON to trigger an error, which if spilled to the client side, may reveal vital information about the system. Or if the JSON was both malformed and contained some text with `<script>...`, and the error is spilled to the client side, you have an XSS bug right there. Therefore IMO it's important to handle JSON errors right where you parse it.

Comment: @Krumia: Are you talking about security holes in user-supplied JSON that was added via the require statement?  I think var config = require(jsonFile); will be literally as "user-supplied" as any other source code, correct?  It would be handled at source compile-time.

Comment: @NickSteele: No, I'm talking about `JSON.parse` here. That's why I wrote *If you are unsure if whatever that is passed to `JSON.parse()` is valid JSON...*.

Comment: @Krumia: You're saying to avoid require(jsonFile) ("Seriously! Use JSON.parse [instead of require]" & "You wanna use require? Think again!")... This is wrong: Node was actually designed to accept requires with json extensions by design, specifically for app config.  There is no security issue with remembering to add the .json extension... one line is much less buggy than 5+ lines, and why not use the method the product designed for you, instead of your own ad-hoc method?  You say "this is not recommended", yet it's not only recommended, it's designed that way for app config.

Comment: @NickSteele: (a) I'm not saying require has a security issue. The part about require is a separate heading among other headings like "`jsonfile` module", "streams", and "error handling". So I'm not sure how you came to that conclusion. They are even separated with <hr>. (b) I don't care if `require` was designed to work with JSON. My points 1, 2, and 3 are still valid concerns. If they are not a concern for the reader, fine! But I'll still leave them here so they are informed.

Comment: @NickSteele: However, I changed "this is not recommended" to "I do not recommend". I hope you are happy now.

Comment: @Krumia Not happy but not sad either, so I guess that's good? :) It's just Node was **designed** to take in config using require(JSON)... so suggesting it not be used seems... you know... wrong and misleading for that case.  It's like you're saying "don't ever take public transportation because you have less freedom"... when you know... it has a real and designated purpose.

Comment: @NickSteele: Given the flaws I have listed I don't think it's a *well designed* feature. Looks to me like some people thought "hey, wouldn't it be cool to use `require` to include JSON?" and didn't even bother documenting the side effects. This also meant that require accepts files in two languages: JavaScript, and JSON (no they're not the same). So much for SRP.

Comment: @Krumia You listed only 3 "side effects" and they are actually all there by *design*... so I'm not sure what you're referring to... It's a good thing to enforce JSON if you use the json extension, is it not?  Wouldn't you complain otherwise? I know that would be a **real** and actual security risk to using this mechanism for config...?? And since config only happens once... isn't it a good thing to load it only once? :)  And since config actually sets up your app, and **must** be synchronous, isn't it good that it's synchronous, like, idunno, maybe it was by design? :)  This is **config**.

Comment: @NickSteele: Yes, only for config it works fine. But JSON is not used only for config.

Comment: @Krumia OK, but you aren't saying it's OK for config, you're saying "You wanna use require? Think again!", and "seriously, use JSON.parse".  I toooootally agree with you, except for config... that's what require(json) was designed for and the only use case.  Your're clearly a genius and your answers get raised above others, so people looking for config directions are seeing your great answer and thinking it also applies to config, because it's a blanket statement.

Answer (score 87):

use the [JSON object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON):

```
JSON.parse(str);
```

Comment: This just duplicates the top answer. Please consider deleting it; you'll keep the points.

Comment: @DanDascalescu - This answer is 3 years old, who cares?

Comment: This answer has 50 upvotes. According to the [1% rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1%25_rule_%28Internet_culture%29), probably 5000 users have spent time reading this answer, which adds nothing to the top one. The fact that it's 3 years old only makes the problem worse :)

Comment: @DanDascalescu -- If you'll notice, the two answers were posted at exactly the same time 3 years ago.  They both provide the same information.  This is the case all over SO, I'm not about to go culling half of my answers just because they weren't the accepted answer.

Comment: @DanDascalescu -- My point is that unless you've taken it upon yourself to police all SO posts, comments like this just add to the noise you seem to be so affected by.

Comment: They add to the noise of the answerer doesn't collaborate. Otherwise, the comment(s) would be deleted along with it.

Comment: What are some objective reasons why you disagree with my suggestion of removing this particular answer?

Comment: I for one found this series of comments fairly interesting but the answer itself to be a waste of my time. ...I'm not sure if that implies that the answer should be deleted, because then I wouldn't have seen the comment thread. But otherwise I'd say yeah.

Comment: @DanDascalescu, I believe this answer is clearer and straight to the point. The accepted one doesn't give a usage example and is confusing because of many links and extra stuff.

Comment: This just duplicates the first answer.

Answer (score 37):

Another example of JSON.parse :

```
var fs = require('fs');
var file = __dirname + '/config.json';

fs.readFile(file, 'utf8', function (err, data) {
  if (err) {
    console.log('Error: ' + err);
    return;
  }

  data = JSON.parse(data);

  console.dir(data);
});
```

Comment: I like that this approach does not require the json file to be local to the application.  Thank you!

Answer (score 35):

I'd like to mention that there are alternatives to the global JSON object.
`JSON.parse` and `JSON.stringify` are both synchronous, so if you want to deal with big objects you might want to check out some of the asynchronous JSON modules.

Have a look: https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/Modules#wiki-parsers-json

Comment: This is especially true if one expects JSON data from incoming connections. If malformed JSON is being parsed by `JSON.parse` your whole application is going to crash or, using `process.on('uncaughtException', function(err) { ... });`, there will eventually be no chance to send a "malformed JSON" error to the user.

Comment: Which one is `async` parser ? I did not find it.

Comment: The linked page is now marked "DEPRECATED" and describes itself as a "faded relic".

Answer (score 30):

Include the `node-fs` library.

```
var fs = require("fs");
var file = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync("./PATH/data.json", "utf8"));
```

For more info on 'fs' library , refer the documentation at http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html

Comment: It might be worth noting that you should wrap your var file line  in a try/catch just in case your JSON fails to parse or the file does not exist.

Comment: Or just use a callback!

Answer (score 12):

Since you don't know that your string is actually valid, I would put it first into a try catch. Also since try catch blocks are not optimized by node, i would put the entire thing into another function:

```
function tryParseJson(str) {
    try {
        return JSON.parse(str);
    } catch (ex) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

OR in "async style"

```
function tryParseJson(str, callback) {
    process.nextTick(function () {
      try {
          callback(null, JSON.parse(str));
      } catch (ex) {
          callback(ex)
      }
    })
}
```

Comment: I just want to make a note that process.nextTick is not aysnc. It's just putting off reading the file until the next function call in the JS event loop. To run JSON.parse asynchronously you have use a different thread than the main Node.js thread

Answer (score 9):

Parsing a JSON stream? Use `JSONStream`.

```
var request = require('request')
  , JSONStream = require('JSONStream')

request({url: 'http://isaacs.couchone.com/registry/_all_docs'})
    .pipe(JSONStream.parse('rows.*'))
    .pipe(es.mapSync(function (data) {
      return data
    }))
```

https://github.com/dominictarr/JSONStream

Answer (score 7):

```
JSON.parse("your string");
```

That's all.

Answer (score 7):

Everybody here has told about JSON.parse, so I thought of saying something else. There is a great module [Connect](http://www.senchalabs.org/connect/) with many middleware to make development of apps easier and better. One of the middleware is [bodyParser](http://www.senchalabs.org/connect/bodyParser.html). It parses JSON, html-forms and etc. There is also a specific middleware for JSON parsing only [noop](http://www.senchalabs.org/connect/json.html).

Take a look at the links above, it might be really helpful to you.

Answer (score 6):

as other answers here have mentioned, you probably want to either require a local json file that you know is safe and present, like a configuration file:

```
var objectFromRequire = require('path/to/my/config.json');
```

or to use the global JSON object to parse a string value into an object:

```
var stringContainingJson = '\"json that is obtained from somewhere\"';
var objectFromParse = JSON.parse(stringContainingJson);
```

note that when you require a file the content of that file is evaluated, which introduces a security risk in case it's not a json file but a js file.

here, i've published a demo where you can see both methods and play with them online (the parsing example is in app.js file - then click on the run button and see the result in the terminal):
http://staging1.codefresh.io/labs/api/env/json-parse-example

you can modify the code and see the impact...

Answer (score 5):

**Using JSON for your configuration with Node.js? Read this and get your configuration skills over 9000...**

> Note: People claiming that data = require('./data.json'); is a
>   security risk and downvoting people's answers with zealous zeal: You're exactly and completely ***wrong***.
>   Try placing non-JSON in that file... Node will give you an error, *exactly* like it would if you did the same thing with the *much* slower and harder to code manual file read and then subsequent JSON.parse().  Please stop spreading misinformation; you're hurting the world, not helping.  Node was **designed** to allow this; **it is not a security risk!**

Proper applications come in 3+ ***layers*** of configuration:

1. Server/Container config
2. Application config
3. (optional) Tenant/Community/Organization config
4. User config

Most developers treat their server and app config as if it can change.  It can't.  You can *layer changes* from higher layers on top of each other, but you're *modifying base requirements*. Some things *need* to exist!  Make your config act like it's immutable, because some of it basically is, just like your source code.

Failing to see that lots of your stuff isn't going to change after startup leads to anti-patterns like littering your config loading with try/catch blocks, and pretending you can continue **without** your properly setup application.  You can't. If you can, that belongs in the community/user config layer, not the server/app config layer.  You're just doing it wrong.  The optional stuff should be layered on top when the application finishes it's bootstrap.

Stop banging your head against the wall: Your config should be **ultra simple**.

Take a look at how easy it is to setup something as complex as a protocol-agnostic and datasource-agnostic service framework using a simple json config file and simple app.js file...

**container-config.js...**

```
{
    "service": {
        "type"  : "http",
        "name"  : "login",
        "port"  : 8085
    },
    "data": {
        "type"  : "mysql",
        "host"  : "localhost",
        "user"  : "notRoot",
        "pass"  : "oober1337",
        "name"  : "connect"
    }
}
```

**index.js...** (the engine that powers everything)

```
var config      = require('./container-config.json');       // Get our service configuration.
var data        = require(config.data.type);            // Load our data source plugin ('npm install mysql' for mysql).
var service     = require(config.service.type);         // Load our service plugin ('http' is built-in to node).
var processor   = require('./app.js');                  // Load our processor (the code you write).

var connection  = data.createConnection({ host: config.data.host, user: config.data.user, password: config.data.pass, database: config.data.name });
var server      = service.createServer(processor);
connection.connect();
server.listen(config.service.port, function() { console.log("%s service listening on port %s", config.service.type, config.service.port); });
```

**app.js...** (the code that powers your protocol-agnostic and data-source agnostic service)

```
module.exports = function(request, response){
    response.end('Responding to: ' + request.url);
}
```

Using this pattern, you can now load community and user config stuff on top of your booted app, dev ops is ready to shove your work into a container and scale it.  You're read for multitenant.  Userland is isolated.  You can now separate the concerns of which service protocol you're using, which database type you're using, and just focus on writing good code.

Because you're using layers, you can rely on a single source of truth for everything, at any time (the layered config object), and avoid error checks at every step, worrying about "oh crap, how am I going to make *this* work without proper config?!?".

Answer (score 5):

If you need to parse JSON with Node.js in a secure way (aka: the user can input data, or a public API) I would suggest using [secure-json-parse](https://www.npmjs.com/package/secure-json-parse).

The usage is like the default `JSON.parse` but it will protect your code from:

- [prototype poisoning](https://medium.com/intrinsic/javascript-prototype-poisoning-vulnerabilities-in-the-wild-7bc15347c96)
- and [constructor abuse](https://hackerone.com/reports/430291):

```js
const badJson = '{ "a": 5, "b": 6, "__proto__": { "x": 7 }, "constructor": {"prototype": {"bar": "baz"} } }'

const infected = JSON.parse(badJson)
console.log(infected.x) // print undefined

const x = Object.assign({}, infected)
console.log(x.x) // print 7

const sjson = require('secure-json-parse')
console.log(sjson.parse(badJson)) // it will throw by default, you can ignore malicious data also
```

Answer (score 4):

My solution:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var file = __dirname + '/config.json';

fs.readFile(file, 'utf8', function (err, data) {
    if (err) {
        console.log('Error: ' + err);
        return;
    }

    data = JSON.parse(data);

    console.dir(data);
});
```

Comment: Thanks @eloyesp, I tried using this code but I keep getting `TypeError: path must be a string or Buffer` errors - any idea where to start debugging this issue?

Answer (score 4):

Just want to complete the answer (as I struggled with it for a while), want to show how to access the json information, this example shows accessing Json Array:

```js
var request = require('request');
request('https://server/run?oper=get_groups_joined_by_user_id&user_id=5111298845048832', function (error, response, body) {
  if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
    var jsonArr = JSON.parse(body);
    console.log(jsonArr);
    console.log("group id:" + jsonArr[0].id);
  }
})
```

Answer (score 3):

Just to make this as complicated as possible, and bring in as many packages as possible...

```
const fs = require('fs');
const bluebird = require('bluebird');
const _ = require('lodash');
const readTextFile = _.partial(bluebird.promisify(fs.readFile), _, {encoding:'utf8',flag:'r'});
const readJsonFile = filename => readTextFile(filename).then(JSON.parse);
```

This lets you do:

```
var dataPromise = readJsonFile("foo.json");
dataPromise.then(console.log);
```

Or if you're using async/await:

```
let data = await readJsonFile("foo.json");
```

The advantage over just using `readFileSync` is that your Node server can process other requests while the file is being read off disk.

Answer (score 2):

JSON.parse will not ensure safety of json string you are parsing. You should look at a library like [json-safe-parse](https://www.npmjs.com/package/json-safe-parse) or a similar library.

From json-safe-parse npm page:

> JSON.parse is great, but it has one serious flaw in the context of JavaScript: it allows you to override inherited properties. This can become an issue if you are parsing JSON from an untrusted source (eg: a user), and calling functions on it you would expect to exist.

Answer (score 2):

Leverage Lodash's attempt function to return an error object, which you can handle with the isError function.

```
// Returns an error object on failure
function parseJSON(jsonString) {
   return _.attempt(JSON.parse.bind(null, jsonString));
}


// Example Usage
var goodJson = '{"id":123}';
var badJson = '{id:123}';
var goodResult = parseJSON(goodJson);
var badResult = parseJSON(badJson);

if (_.isError(goodResult)) {
   console.log('goodResult: handle error');
} else {
   console.log('goodResult: continue processing');
}
// > goodResult: continue processing

if (_.isError(badResult)) {
   console.log('badResult: handle error');
} else {
   console.log('badResult: continue processing');
}
// > badResult: handle error
```

Comment: Can you explain why you added `.bind` instead of just using _.attempt(JSON.parse, str)

Answer (score 2):

Always be sure to use JSON.parse in **try catch** block as node always throw an Unexpected Error  if you have some corrupted data in your json so use this code instead of simple JSON.Parse

```
try{
     JSON.parse(data)
}
catch(e){
   throw new Error("data is corrupted")
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `JSON.parse(str);`. Read more about it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse).

Here are some examples:

```
var jsonStr = '{"result":true, "count":42}';

obj = JSON.parse(jsonStr);

console.log(obj.count);    // expected output: 42
console.log(obj.result);   // expected output: true
```

Answer (score 2):

I use [fs-extra](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fs-extra). I like it a lot because -although it supports callbacks- it also supports [Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise). So it just enables me to write my code in a much more readable way:

```
const fs = require('fs-extra');
fs.readJson("path/to/foo.json").then(obj => {
    //Do dome stuff with obj
})
.catch(err => {
    console.error(err);
});
```

It also has many useful methods which do not come along with the standard `fs` module *and*, on top of that, it also bridges the methods from the native `fs` module and promisifies them.

> NOTE: You can still use the native Node.js methods. They are promisified and copied over to fs-extra. See notes on `fs.read()` & `fs.write()`

So it's basically all advantages. I hope others find this useful.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the above answers, We can use `JSON.parse()` to parse the strings to JSON
But before parsing, be sure to parse the correct data or else it might bring your whole application down

it is safe to use it like this

```
let parsedObj = {}
try {
    parsedObj = JSON.parse(data);
} catch(e) {
    console.log("Cannot parse because data is not is proper json format")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add some comments in your JSON and allow trailing commas you might want use below implemention:

```
var fs = require('fs');

var data = parseJsData('./message.json');

console.log('[INFO] data:', data);

function parseJsData(filename) {
    var json = fs.readFileSync(filename, 'utf8')
        .replace(/\s*\/\/.+/g, '')
        .replace(/,(\s*\})/g, '}')
    ;
    return JSON.parse(json);
}
```

Note that it might not work well if you have something like `"abc": "foo // bar"` in your JSON. So YMMV.

Answer (score 1):

If the JSON source file is pretty big, may want to consider the asynchronous route via native async / await approach with Node.js 8.0 as follows

```
const fs = require('fs')

const fsReadFile = (fileName) => {
    fileName = `${__dirname}/${fileName}`
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        fs.readFile(fileName, 'utf8', (error, data) => {
            if (!error && data) {
                resolve(data)
            } else {
                reject(error);
            }
        });
    })
}

async function parseJSON(fileName) {
    try {
        return JSON.parse(await fsReadFile(fileName));
    } catch (err) {
        return { Error: `Something has gone wrong: ${err}` };
    }
}

parseJSON('veryBigFile.json')
    .then(res => console.log(res))
    .catch(err => console.log(err))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use JSON.parse() (which is a built in function that will probably force you to wrap it with try-catch statements).

Or use some JSON parsing npm library, something like [json-parse-or](https://www.npmjs.com/package/parse-json-or)

Answer (score 0):

Use this to be on the safe side

```
var data = JSON.parse(Buffer.concat(arr).toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

**NodeJs** is a **JavaScript** based server, so you can do the way you do that in pure **JavaScript**...

Imagine you have this **Json** in **NodeJs**...

```
var details = '{ "name": "Alireza Dezfoolian", "netWorth": "$0" }';
var obj = JSON.parse(details);
```

And you can do above to get a parsed version of your json...

Answer (score -1):

No further modules need to be required.
Just use
`var parsedObj = JSON.parse(yourObj);`
I don think there is any security issues regarding this

Answer (score -2):

It's simple, you can convert JSON to string using `JSON.stringify(json_obj)`, and convert string to JSON using `JSON.parse("your json string")`.

Comment: Have you looked at the top answer for this question? It's 3 years old and very complete. What were you hoping to contribute with the trivial information you're offering here?

Comment: Now, now, let's not hold a double standard

Answer (score -3):

```
var fs = require('fs');

fs.readFile('ashish.json',{encoding:'utf8'},function(data,err) {

   if(err) 
      throw err;

   else {

   console.log(data.toString());

 }
})
```

Comment: While this may be an answer, please provide some context and explanation.   Code only answers are not very useful for future visitors.. and may be deleted.