# Node.JS: Can't use require to parse .json file in REPL

Tags: json, node.js, parsing, require, read-eval-print-loop

So I'm trying to parse a config.json file from the REPL.
The file is: app/config/config.json and I'm running the REPL from app/.

In the REPL if I try to require the file, the REPL doesn't execute, instead waiting for more input:

```
$ node
> var config = require('./config/config.json');
...
```

I'm sure it can be done, but I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/9804910/1027966

Comment: Is your config.json valid? Test it with http://jsonlint.com

Comment: This solved my problem.  I did not have valid json.  Remember to escape backslashes folks!

Comment: Nick, please post and accept an answer so people don't waste time on this question now that it is solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out you cant use Node.js' require to parse JSON if the JSON is invalid.  That behavior I witnessed occurs when the parsed JSON is invalid.