# Javascript: How to load JSON object as a file without jQuery or AJAX?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to parse JSON using NodeJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5726729/how-to-parse-json-using-nodejs)

I am running a server. The code is run on the server with Node.js -- never run in a browser.

How can I load a JSON file ("data.json") into javascript code as a javascript object? Should I just use jQuery/AJAX to do this? Is there a simple way with plain js? Thanks in advance! BTW I searched for this on both Google and this website without any clear answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at [this](http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_open_path_flags_mode_callback)

Read the whole contents of the file, and then just parse it.
Have a look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5726729/how-to-parse-json-using-nodejs).