# Get a JSON via HTTP request in NodeJS

Tags: json, node.js, api, httprequest

Here  is my model with a JSON response:

```
exports.getUser = function(req, res, callback) {
    User.find(req.body, function (err, data) {
        if (err) {
            res.json(err.errors);
        } else {
            res.json(data);
        }
   });
};
```

Here I get it via `http.request`. Why do I receive (data) a string and not a JSON?

```
 var options = {
  hostname: '127.0.0.1'
  ,port: app.get('port')
  ,path: '/users'
  ,method: 'GET'
  ,headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }
};

var req = http.request(options, function(res) {
  res.setEncoding('utf8');
  res.on('data', function (data) {
       console.log(data); // I can't parse it because, it's a string. why?
  });
});
reqA.on('error', function(e) {
  console.log('problem with request: ' + e.message);
});
reqA.end();
```

How can I get a JSON?

Comment: JSON is a serialization. It's only JSON if it's in a string, or otherwise not-yet-parsed as JavaScript.
 Are you looking for `JSON.parse()`?

Comment: I thought the `data` event was called multiple times each time with an argument that is a chunk of the string data. Wouldn't it be quite likely that the `data` returned in that event be broken JSON because it's only a fraction of the total document? I think you need to buffer the data and then use `JSON.parse()` in your `end` event.

Comment: You're right, it sends in chunks , so the best way is create a Buffer array and push it there

Comment: Seeing nodejs question asked by Sasha Grey....:D

Comment: Also notice that reqA is not defined in your code

Answer (score 92, accepted):

http sends/receives data as strings... this is just the way things are.  You are looking to parse the string as json.

```
var jsonObject = JSON.parse(data);
```

[How to parse JSON using Node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5726729/how-to-parse-json-using-nodejs)

Answer (score 76):

Just tell request that you are using json:true and forget about header and parse

```
var options = {
    hostname: '127.0.0.1',
    port: app.get('port'),
    path: '/users',
    method: 'GET',
    json:true
}
request(options, function(error, response, body){
    if(error) console.log(error);
    else console.log(body);
});
```

and the same for post

```
var options = {
    hostname: '127.0.0.1',
    port: app.get('port'),
    path: '/users',
    method: 'POST',
    json: {"name":"John", "lastname":"Doe"}
}
request(options, function(error, response, body){
    if(error) console.log(error);
    else console.log(body);
});
```

Comment: I knew that request was able to give a JSON body but the documentation really wasn't clear on that part! Saves doing a redundant parse. I also get the feeling you can do `response.toJSON()`

Comment: This does not work for `http.request`, rather [request](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request).

Answer (score 25):

Just setting `json` option to `true`, the body will contain the parsed JSON:

```
request({
  url: 'http://...',
  json: true
}, function(error, response, body) {
  console.log(body);
});
```

Comment: this doesn't work for me. It must be for [request lib](https://npmjs.com/request), not `http.request`