# How to get the JSON I want using an HTTP request on node.js?

Tags: node.js, parsing

```
var request = require('request');

request.post(
    'http://www.yoursite.com/formpage',
    { json: { key: 'value' } },
    function (error, response, body) {
        if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
            console.log(body)
        }
    }
);
```

But the issue I have is not knowing how to parse and adjust the code.

```
"entities": [
    {
      "entity": "today",
      "type": "builtin.datetimeV2.date",
      "startIndex": 0,
      "endIndex": 4,
      "resolution": {
        "values": [
          {
            "timex": "2017-12-13",
            "type": "date",
            "value": "2017-12-13"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

The value I want from this JSON is today in entity.

How can I adjust the code to give me that exact entity I want ?

Comment: You should give it a try. Refs: https://stackoverflow.com/q/17811827/1531971 and many others found with a web search.

Comment: Did you `JSON.parse` it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use for example Chrome Developer tools, if you are unsure. Copy & paste the complete JSON string, and then press

Ctrtl + Shift + J

```
testvar = {"entities": [
{
  "entity": "today",
  "type": "builtin.datetimeV2.date",
  "startIndex": 0,
  "endIndex": 4,
  "resolution": {
    "values": [
          {
            "timex": "2017-12-13",
             "type": "date",
             "value": "2017-12-13"
           }
         ]
       }
     }
   ]
 };
```

Now you can just enter

```
testvar
```

into the console window

And you will see:

```
{entities: Array(1)}
```

you can now expand the variable by clicking the expand icon.

Entering

```
testvar.entities[0]
```

will show you everthing below the first array item. Entering

```
testvar.entities[0].entity
```

will show

```
today
```

This approach using developer tools can be easier if you are new to JSON or the structures are too nested.

In addition to your comment

"The thing is i don't want such a pin point method because i'll be checking the type, and if the type matchs the one i'm expecting i'll take that enitty value"

You can always check whether a node exists.

For example....

```
   typeof(body);
   "object"

   typeof(body.entities);
   "object"

   typeof(body.testxyz);
   "undefined"

   typeof(body.entities[0].resolution.values);
   "object"
```

You can check for these in your conditions.

Additionally, you can retrieve the number of items within a node.

```
   Object.keys(body.entities[0].resolution.values).length
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

entities is an Array, so if you want to get the first element of entities, you just have to do something like this:

```
console.log(body.entities[0].entity);
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: The thing is i don't want such a pin point method because i'll be checking the type, and if the type matchs the one i'm expecting i'll take that enitty value.