# Nodejs net send json?

Tags: node.js

I am trying to send json formated data over a net socket in nodejs like this:

```
socket.write("{\"id\":\"1\", \"type\":message, \"msg\": " + obj.msg + ", \"name\": " + obj.msg + ", \"time\": " + getDateTime() + "}", socket);
```

For some reason this does not work, any ideas what i am doing wrong?

Comment: Look into this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5726729/how-to-parse-json-using-nodejs

Answer (score 1):

There are few node.js modules that can help:

- json-over-tcp: https://www.npmjs.org/package/json-over-tcp
- json-socket: https://www.npmjs.org/package/json-socket

Simple way is to use the JSON object (ECMAScript 5) with simply converting any object to string using [JSON.stringify()](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_stringify.asp). Use the returned string to send over the socket.

Answer (score 0):

```
socket.write(JSON.Stringify({
   data: "stuff"
});
```

Then use JSON.Parse on the other side. This is how I'm doing it.

Comment: There is a  problem with this. The tcp socket doesn't guarantee that each string you write would be separately sent. So you might receive two or more lines as part of a single message. To avoid this situation the data protocol needs to specify either the number of bytes to read or a special terminating character.