# Artifactory: is there a way to customize GUI in Artifactory Pro

Tags: javascript, groovy, artifactory, artifacts, artifact

I have been working in Artifactory User plugins for couple of weeks. 
All custom user plugins are run from the server side in groovy. I am looking for a way to write a plugin that runs on browser/client side.

My requirement is: Validate an Artifact with custom validation and throw popup dialog for any errors? So is there a way where we can customize Artifactory GUI to write javascript to show popup dialogs which will be called before a download is triggered.

A quick comments/ suggestions would be very grateful.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you are familiar with User Plugins, you are half way there. What you should do is write execution plugins that consume and return the needed info in json format, and create a js frontend (node.js or similar) that will talk to those plugins by json.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I don't know what node.js is. I started looking into it, could you share some examples on how we can use node.js or handle json in Artifactory? Thanks again.

Comment: I am not a node.js pro myself, but [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5726729/how-to-parse-json-using-nodejs) looks like something you might find useful.