# turf and unkink polygon in geojson

Tags: node.js, command-line, geojson, turfjs

I'm trying to automatically remove a self-intersection from a geojson file.  [Another stackexchange site suggested I use a package called turf](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/304439/command-line-tool-to-repair-self-intersection-in-geojson).

I'm not quite familiar with how I should set up the IO.  The file I am trying to fix is here:

- https://github.com/OpenDataDE/State-zip-code-GeoJSON/blob/master/ks_kansas_zip_codes_geo.min.json

I am trying this:

```
const fname="ks_kansas_zip_codes_geo.min.json";
const fout="fixed_kansas.json";
const turf = require('@turf/turf');
const fs = require('fs');
var tmp = fs.readFile(fname, function(err, x) {
   var fixed = turf.unkinkPolygon(turf.polygon(x));
   console.log(fixed);
   return(fixed)
  });
// fs.writeFileSync(fout, tmp);
```

<strike>The error I get is:</strike>

```
Error: coordinates is required
   at polygon (/home/username/node_modules/@turf/helpers/main.js:229:29)
```

The error I get is:

```
undefined
> { type: 'FeatureCollection', features: [] }

> tmp
undefined
```

Not really sure how to use this library to operate on a geojson file.  I see a [couple](http://thecodebarbarian.com/wrangling-geojson-with-turf.html) of [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22761983/how-to-load-json-data-on-node-js) [examples](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@turf/unkink-polygon), but nothing end-to-end that would help me even load it so I can make what I'm looking for, which is more like:

```
node myscript.js ks_kansas_zip_codes_geo.min.json fixed_ks.json
```

Comment: Did you resolved the issue? If yes, you can share your experience

Comment: No, I have no resolution.