# Node.js Express: loading JSON file only on server startup

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, express, swagger

I'm working on an express.js app which should load an API definition file (most likely the swagger file in JSON format). Currently I've created a middleware, which should parse the JSON file via `fs.readFile()` and `JSON.parse()` in order to check user's permissions on accessing some resource. So basically **each** time the request is performed, my middleware gets the same JSON file and parses it, which is obviously a piece of extra work. Is it possible to load this JSON file, parse and store it to some internal object in a sort of global configuration and reload it in case it was modified so as not to perform the same operation on each request?

Comment: FYI you can `require` json.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course, you could create a function like this (pseudo code):

```
var jsonData=null;

function getConfiguration() {
  if (!jsonData) {
    jsonData= readFileSync(...);
  }
  return jsonData;
}

module.exports.getConfiguration=getConfiguration;
```

Or, as @AleksandrM commented, you can just "import" it using [require](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9804910/1919228):

Comment: Should this be included in separate middleware? in that case, how to pass it to the appropriate middleware?

Comment: I'm not sure if that function could work as on every request the `var jsonData` is set to null, and `if (!jsonData)` gets evaluated every time

Comment: No, the variable is only declared (and set to null) once. Calling the function  does not reset its value. You can create a node module with that piece of code and import it wherever you need it

Comment: Sorry for misunderstanding - now it works like a charm. The mistake was to use your suggested code **in** `module.exports` function, which indeed gets called on every request, that's my lack of experience with Node and Express. Thanks a million for your help!

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me, very much aligned with the answer here

```
let config_file = path.join(__dirname, 'config.json')
let configJSON = {}


function getConfiguration() {
    jsonfile.readFile(config_file, function (err, obj) {
    if (err) console.error(err)
    console.dir(obj)
    configJSON = obj
})}
```

Then on app startup

```
app.listen(port, () => {
  getConfiguration()
  console.log(`App listening at http://localhost:${port}`)
})
```