# Extract each values from a collection of values in node js

Tags: json, node.js

How can I extract each values separately from this collection of values using node js

```
{"username":"myname","password":"mypassword"}
```

Comment: This is a Basic Basic question. did u know JSON? Whether googled it?.

Comment: Yeah.. I know json. but its not json formatted data

Comment: The above is JSON. Do JSON.parse(your string) it will be json formatted.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5726729/how-to-parse-json-using-node-js

Comment: @ sambellerose- I am a beginner in this type of javascript code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var obj = {"username":"myname","password":"mypassword"};

obj.username;
obj.password;
```