# How to Convert C# Values to Node.js Object

Tags: c#

I have simple C# object instantiated like

```
User theUser = new User("John", "Doe");
```

now I need to load it to my Node.js file like:

```
var theUser = {name:"John", lastName:"Doe"};
```

Can you please let me know how to do that? Do I have to save/write the output on a separate json file? or..?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "load it" to your Node.js file?

Comment: Hi David I have a server side Javascript which is suppose to send the following data to another server using node and Ajax , I hope this was helpful!

Comment: It seems like an odd step to convert to JS for Node when C# can send it to the other server directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you intend to use JSON as bridge from C# to Nodejs, use JavaScriptSerializer class to convert your C# class as JSON data.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx

C#

```
// your data class
public class YourClassName
{
    ...
}

// Javascript serialization
using System.IO;
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;

String json = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(YourClassName);
File.WriteAllText("json_file_path", json);
```

Node.js

```
// Async mode
var jsondata = require('fs').readFile('json_file_path', 'utf8', function (err, data) {
    if (err) throw err; // throw error if not found or invalid
    var obj = JSON.parse(jsondata);
});

// Sync mode
var jsondata = JSON.parse(require('fs').readFileSync('json_file_path', 'utf8'));
```

Node.js reference: [How to parse JSON using Node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5726729/how-to-parse-json-using-node-js)

Hopefully this is useful, CMIIW.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use `Newtonsoft.Json` - add a reference to this within your project.

To convert the object from a known type to json string;

```
string output = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(theUser);
```

To convert the object to a dynamic type;

```
dynamic json = JToken.Parse(theUser); - to dynamic
```

[MSDN Link](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/serializingjson.htm) for extra help, if needed.