# How to iterate through an array inside an object?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a config.json file:

```
{
  "test": {
    "maths": [
      "core",
      "core2"
    ]
  }
}
```

In my index.js, I want to access the object 'test', and iterate through each of the maths elements.

I am new to arrays, so still trying to figure out how they work. What is wrong with this approach? (I know it does not work)

```
var CONFIG = require('./config.json')

var fn = CONFIG.test.maths

fn.forEach(function(value){
console.log(value);
});
```

Also, what is the correct way of doing this?

Comment: You can check this answer; http://stackoverflow.com/a/10167931/2324048

Comment: Did you miss the semi-colons?

Comment: The semicolons are not a problem in this case. I get this error : TypeError: Cannot read property 'maths' of undefined

Comment: Do you have node.js installed? `require` is not a native function, but a function defined in node.js

Comment: Yes all of that is setup correctly

Comment: Oh, sorry, but change to `JSON.parse(require('./config'))`

Comment: I get this error: undefined:1
[object Object]
 ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token o

Comment: To require a json file as you're trying to do, it must have the `.json` extension. If not, you'll have to use `JSON.parse(require('fs').readFile('./config.js'))`

Comment: you can get object by this way also  
 var demo = {"test": {"maths": ["core","core2"]}}
  $.each(demo,function(key,value){
       $.each(value,function(getket,getvalue){
        alert(getvalue);
       });
      });
    alert(JSON.stringify(demo));

Comment: Any updates to see?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing config.js to

```
module.exports = {
  "test": {
    "maths": [
      "core",
      "core2"
    ]
  }
};
```

As it stands now - your module doesn't export anything.

**Update:** if you prefer .json - this method won't work as .json can't be exported (but it can be required in node, see [How to parse JSON using Node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5726729/how-to-parse-json-using-node-js)), it works with .js files as modules. And you'll have to change this part too:

```
require('./config.js')
```

**Update2:** it works as is with
index.js

```
var CONFIG = require('./config')

var fn = CONFIG.test.maths

fn.forEach(function(value){
console.log(value);
});
```

config.json

```
{
  "test": {
    "maths": [
      "core",
      "core2"
    ]
  }
}
```

in my node v5.3.0

Answer (score 0):

To fix this rename your config.js file to config.json (For naming convention sake)

Change:

```
var CONFIG = require('./config')
```

To:

```
var CONFIG = require('./config.json')
```

The reason is that requiring a file requires the exact filename including the extension

Comment: sorry, I mean my file is called config.json (corrected the question). This does not seem to solve anything

Answer (score 0):

3 posible solutions, choose the one that suits you the most:

1. Change the file extension of `config.js` , to `config.json`
2. Read the file instead and parse it as JSON: `var CONFIG = JSON.parse(require('fs').readFile('./config.js'));`
3. Make the file a module that exports the JSON instead of plain JSON, as Anton suggested

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use the JQuery method **getJSON** to load the *Json* into *Javascript*.

```
`$.getJSON( "config.json", function( data ) {
   console.log(data);
   var val = data.test.maths
   val.forEach(function (d) {
     console.log(d);
   })
 });`
```