# In NodeRed, how can I separate values from JSON data sent by the Watson IoT Platform

Tags: javascript, node.js, ibm-cloud, device, watson-iot

How can I get the distance value and how to assign it to another variable.
I get that data from bluemix (Watson IoT Platform) to node-red

```
{distance:"45.9"};
```

I tried like

```
var data=msg.distance;
```

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5726729/how-to-parse-json-using-node-js

Comment: `{distance:"45.9"}` is not JSON. It's a JavaScript object literal.

Comment: from that how can i get value

Comment: I think we are going to need some more context.  Is msg the name of your object?  Are you trying to reference it outside of it's scope?

Comment: my exact use case is I need to get data from ibmiot node and by using that data I need to turn on led by using condition.

Comment: I got data from ibmiot as {distance:"34"} . so now I need to check that value is less than some particular value then I need to turn on led which is on raspberry pi

Comment: I think this is a common issue for NodeRed developers who lack dev experience and would be useful to others IF it is improved.

Answer (score 0):

Use Json.parse to convert the string to an array.Now you can access the elements of the array.

Answer (score 0):

If you include the JSON node it will convert your JS Object to JSON.  But maybe you have messed with the quotes and actually have json; by default you would.

I would add a Debug node to your IoT-In node.  Check what exactly you receive.  And then it is usually easy to parse like (it depends on what you send):

```
var distance = msg.payload.d.distance 
var distance = msg.payload.distance
```

You might want to **edit your Question** to include exactly what you receive in the Debug node and need to parse.

Also be aware that your value for distance is a string, you'll probably want to convert it to a number at somepoint.  If it is in your control, it would be better practice to send it as a number to start with.