# Inserting data from json to mysql using node js

Tags: mysql, json, node.js

How to insert data from JSON file to mysql using node js.

For example :

```
{
    "root": {
        "child": [
            { "textNode": "First & Child" },
            { "textNode": "Second Child" }
        ],
        "testAttrs": {
            "_attr1": "attr1Value"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It's a JSON object. Just make it into a variable, like so:
`var obj = {…your JSON…}` and access it like so: `obj.root.child[0].textNode`, then put each accessed value into the SQL statement. If you're in doubt, `require('fs')` and use `JSON.parse()` on the file.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to parse JSON using Node.js?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5726729/how-to-parse-json-using-node-js)

Comment: Your question is extremely general. 

Do you want to know:

Q1 …how to get the data from the JSON-file and into the application?

Q2: …how to know how to parse the JSON-data?

Q3: …how to access values in the parsed JSON-object?

Q4: …how to implement a Node.js driver plugin for MySQL and use it?

Qn: All of the above?