# How can parse the following JSON Using node JS

Tags: sql, json, node.js

{“recordsets”:[[{“RESPONSE”:“Coming Soon….”}]],“recordset”:[{“RESPONSE”:“Coming Soon….”}],“output”:{},“rowsAffected”:[1]}

Comment: Have you looked up how to parse JSON? Guides exist for it everywhere. You could find one in seconds of searching.

Comment: not familier about node js

Comment: recordsets[0][0]["RESPONSE"]) tried like this its not working ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to parse JSON using Node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5726729/how-to-parse-json-using-node-js)

Comment: Again, please search before asking next time. I've never even used Node.JS and it took seconds to find the answer using Google.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks i can find a solution

data.recordsets[0][0].RESPONSE;