# How to apply encoding to my json file

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I have a json file named `data.json` with data as

```
"data": {
        "val1": "568.000188",
        "val2": "RÃ©union..Ãland Islands,rrrß"
      },
```

But when I am trying to read the file as

```
var result = require(data.json);
```

I am getting result as below

```
"data": {
        "val1": "568.000188",
        "val2": "Réunion..�land Islands,rrr�"
      },
```

Can any one suggest me,how to read the file,so that I'll get exact result?

Thanks

Comment: What writes the JSON file? Because clearly, this is already broken.

Comment: Also, don't `require()` JSON files. It might look like it works, but it's a bad idea. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/25710749/18771