# I'm not able to export the data, fetched from the Database to Excel (.csv) or (xlsx) format in Node.JS

Tags: mysql, node.js

I'm getting the data from database in Json format.

```
[
  {
    "name": "Raj",
    "age": 20,
    "fav-color": "blue"
  },
  {
    "name": "Rahul",
    "age": 23,
    "fav-color": "green"
  },
  {
    "name": "Vijay",
    "age": 21,
    "fav-color": "white"
  },
]
```

I want it to put into the Excel file like,

### name |age|fav-color

raj  | 20| blue

rahul|23 | green

vijay|21 | white

Answer (score 0):

You can use xlsx npm module.
[Go here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xlsx) to this package.

Use json to sheet function for generating Excel sheet.

Comment: yup it looks promising

Answer (score 0):

You can use [json parser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5726729/how-to-parse-json-using-node-js) to read the json document and exporting it into an excel file in your desired format using [poi package](https://poi.js.org/guide/installation.html).

Answer (score 0):

I found ExcelJS library was great to address my problem.

the documentation was done very well,

here is the link to [ExcelJS](https://www.npmjs.com/package/exceljs)