# Extract string between double quote using java

Tags: javascript, json

I'm trying to extract words between double quote. The string that I need to split is a derivate of JSON array converted to string.

My string is represented like this:
{"methodParam":["test1","test2","test3"]}

What I need to do is iterate over this string and obtain only the words inside double quote using .split java method like this:

```
test1

test2

test3
```

I've already tried some regex with bad results

Comment: Parse JSON with a JSON parser, not regex. What language are you using? Java or JavaScript?

Comment: `JavaScript` and `Java` are not the same. Which are you using? Also, include a [mcve] showing what you have attempted. See [ask].

Comment: JSON is not parsable in its entirety using regex (or it becomes infinitely complex), just use a library to parse the JSON

Comment: Yes, this could be a solution but how can I do it with JSON parser? I use javascript to create the JSON and then I pass the result to Java using a java action. I'm not so familiar with JSON so I tried to do it with java

Comment: Json isn't a language, it's a data format

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to parse JSON in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591098/how-to-parse-json-in-java)

Comment: @MatthewKerian I know, but how can I use JSON parser to retrieve only words that I mentioned in the post?

Comment: @MatthewKerian parse the entire object using one of the many JSON parsers, then using that, traverse the object to find the fields you want. You can't just parse a json object partially

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to parse JSON using Node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5726729/how-to-parse-json-using-node-js)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(EDIT: so it is javascript that you wanted?)

### Javascript

Just use `JSON.parse()` to parse it into an object, then manipulate it and get the fields you need

```js
const str = '{"methodParam":["test1","test2","test3"]}';
const obj = JSON.parse(str);
const lst = obj.methodParam;
    
const [ param1, param2, param3 ] = lst;

console.log(param1, param2, param3, " are your parameters!");
```

### Explanation

Javascript's `JSON.parse()` takes in a JSON formatted string, then returns a Javascript `Object`.

Comment: Thanks for the example!! I'll revise the tags of the post